# Modify web.xml With XSLT And Maintain Schema Validity

Tags: validation, xslt, xsd, web.xml

I've been searching for a way to check for the existence of a specific "servlet-mapping" in a Web application deployment descriptor (web.xml) and add it if not found while maintaining Schema validity with XSLT 1.0, however, I'm going cross-eyed trying to figure it out and keep going in circles and probably making it more difficult than it is.

According to the Java Servlet Specification, "servlet-mapping" elements must follow "servlet" if any exist, which in turn must follow "listener" elements if defined and so on.

So, how do I add a "servlet-mapping" element after all other "servlet" elements only if the "servlet-mapping" is not already present.

Here is a paired down web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="2.5"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>listings</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>fork</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my XSLT, which unfortunately puts the "servlet-mapping" element at the beginning of web.xml if not already present:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:jee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
        <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

        <xsl:param name="version.jsp.servlet.name" select="'jsp'"/>
        <xsl:param name="version.jsp.url.pattern" select="'/jsp/*'"/>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="jee:web-app">
                <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

                        <xsl:if test="not(jee:servlet-mapping[jee:servlet-name=$version.jsp.servlet.name and jee:url-pattern=$version.jsp.url.pattern])">
                                <xsl:message>Adding jsp servlet-mapping</xsl:message>
                                <xsl:element name="servlet-mapping">
                                        <xsl:element name="servlet-name">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$version.jsp.servlet.name"/>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                        <xsl:element name="url-pattern">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$version.jsp.url.pattern"/>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've tried using "following-sibling" in the XPath expression to no avail as follows:

```
not(jee:servlet[position()=last()]/following-sibling::jee:servlet-mapping[jee:servlet-name=$version.jsp.servlet.name and jee:url-pattern=$version.jsp.url.pattern])
```

I also need to add a "filter" element followed by a "filter-mapping" element to the XML, however, in this case I obviously need to add them after all "icon", "display-name", "description", "distributable" and "context-param" elements if they exists at all.

How would I construct an XPath expression to account for the preceding required elements if they exist at all?

Comment: Your XML is referencing a schema (xsd) for validation. I edited your question and replaced everything DTD related with schema/xsd.

Comment: The schema for web.xml _doesn't_ enforce ordering like this, that's the principal advantage of using the schema rather than the DTD.

Answer (score 0):

If you put you xsl:if after your apply-templates, it should work.

But maybe adding templates like this may help you too :

```
<!-- It's the last servlet of the input -->
<xsl:template match="jee:servlet[not(following-sibling::jee:servlet)]">
    <!-- First do as usual and copy the servlet -->
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <!-- Then test if you need to output some specific mapping -->
    <xsl:if test="not(jee:servlet-mapping[jee:servlet-name=$version.jsp.servlet.name and jee:url-pattern=$version.jsp.url.pattern])">
    ...
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

But the use of position() in your question can't work as you'd like, because you need "the last servlet in the context", not "a servlet only if it's the last element in the context".
I think with the template example, you'll be able to solve the "filter cases".

And if you're stucked with XSLT 1.0, xsl:next-match won't work. Just give a name to your generic template (match + name attributes) and call it explicitly instead of a xsl:next-match.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:jee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        exclude-result-prefixes="jee">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:param name="version.jsp.servlet.name" select="'jsp'"/>
  <xsl:param name="version.jsp.url.pattern" select="'/jsp/*'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="Copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="jee:servlet[last()]">
    <xsl:call-template name="Copy" />

    <xsl:if test="not(../jee:servlet-mapping
                        [jee:servlet-name = $version.jsp.servlet.name and
                         jee:url-pattern = $version.jsp.url.pattern])">
      <xsl:call-template name="ServletMapping" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="ServletMapping">
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>
        <xsl:value-of select="$version.jsp.servlet.name"/>
      </servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>
        <xsl:value-of select="$version.jsp.url.pattern"/>
      </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```